# VueJS Convert Computed to Method?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I need to convert a computed to a method so I can interact with it in VueJS 2.7. The computed is this...

```
currentPage: (state): number => (state as MyPageData).pagination.currentPage,
```

Tried to just straight up move it to `method: { ... }`

Any help would be appreciated :/

Comment: Syntactically, it can go from `computed` to `methods` no problem. Whether it works the way you want it to depends on how you use it.  Not knowing **anything else** about your app or the purpose of this method or even what exact error/problem you're facing, no one can help.

Comment: [working method](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

As @yoduh pointed out, the answer is this...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div @click="test">click me:{{ val }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
interface MyPageData {
  pagination: {
    currentPage: number
  }
}
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      val: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    currentPage: (state): number => (state as MyPageData).pagination.currentPage,
    test() {
      this.val = this.currentPage({ pagination: { currentPage: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) } })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```